# É possível chamar método internal(sem operador de visibilidade) de uma class herdada de um outro package?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

**Problema**

Estou tentando criar alguns comportamentos extras em alguns componentes nativos do Android.

Para isso estou criando uma `class` acima do componente do Android e reescrevendo algumas situações que pretendo ter um comportamento diferente, e me deparei com uma situação que necessito em meu método customizado, chamar um método da `class` herdada (no caso o componente do Android), mas o método não está acessível para minha `class`, já que ele é internal e não `protected`, e minha `class` está em um outro `package`.

**Perguntas?**

- Apesar de saber que atributos e métodos `internal` só são acessiveis
  para membros do mesmo `package` Java, gostaria de saber se há alguma
  forma de ter acesso a esses métodos a partir de uma `class` de um
  outro `package`?
- E opcionalmente, se há alguma outra forma de sobrescrever
  componentes nativos do Android, quem evitem esse tipo de problema?

**Exemplo do que estou tentando fazer:**

```java
public class MeuAbsListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter>{

    public MeuAbsListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void meuMetodoDisparadoPeloMeuEvento(){
        // faz seu comportamento custumizado ... 

        // e tem esse metodo 'rememberSyncState' do 'AdapterView' que preciso chamar
        // só que ele é internal e não tenho acesso a ele, 
        // já no AbsListView nativo é possivel pois ele é do mesmo package do AdapterView
        rememberSyncState();
    }   
}
```

No código [fonte do AdapterView do Android](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java) o método está declarado assim:

```java
void rememberSyncState() {
    // codigo do rememberSyncState ...
}
```

Comment: Não entendi: "há alguma outra forma de sobrescrever componentes nativos do Android, quem evitem esse tipo de problema?" Você quer criar uma subclasse que torne a visibilidade de um método da classe menos restritiva do que na superclasse?

Comment: @Math, é por ai, acredito que isso não seja possível, já que vai contra tudo, mas queria tirar a duvida.

Comment: Falei besteira no meu comentário anterior, você não pode deixar MAIS restritivo, ou seja, se você tem um método sem modificador você pode deixar ele menos restritivo em uma sobrescrita de uma subclasse sua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A duas formas de conseguir isso através de adaptações técnicas emergenciais (a.k.a *Gambiarra*).

Funciona em java mas [não no android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27012/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-chamar-m%c3%a9todo-internalsem-operador-de-visibilidade-de-uma-class-her/27017?noredirect=1#comment50502_27017)

**1.Crie uma terceira classe herdeira no mesmo pacote da Classe restritiva**

```
public class ClasseRestritiva
{
   protected void foo(){}
}
```

e

```
public MinhaClasseNaoRestritiva extends ClasseRestritiva
{

     public void chamaFoo()
     {
           foo();
     }

}
```

**2. Reflections**

Existe um exemplo bom [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664192/accessing-protected-method-in-test-case-using-java-reflection) do SOEN. Além disso recomendo que veja a [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

**Solução com Reflection**

```java
Method rememberSyncState = AdapterView.class.getDeclaredMethod("rememberSyncState");
// Set accessible provide a way to access private methods too
rememberSyncState.setAccessible(true);
// this é instancia da class que herda de AdapterView
rememberSyncState.invoke(this);
```

Comment: É possível criar uma `class` no mesmo `package` dos componentes nativos do Android? No caso `android.widget`?

Comment: Já tentou criar o package `android.widget` e colocar algo lá no seu projeto?

Comment: Já tinha tentado fazer isso anteriormente, e tentei agora de novo, mas não deu certo. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: @Fernando tentou usar `reflection`? *Nota* achei que era possível pois pode-se colocar classes em `java.io`. Nunca trabalhei de fato com android.

Comment: Acho que reflection funciona. Ja consegui acessar atributos private de uma superclasse que não era minha. Não tenho certeza em relação a métodos, mas vale a tentativa.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun, _reflection_ funcionou, vou editar sua pergunta e colocar como fiz. (Graça a "adaptações técnicas emergenciais (a.k.a Gambiarra).").