# Converter List<T> para T... dinamicamente na chamada de um metodo

Tags: java, genéricos, reflexão

Estou necessitando de algo que parece ser simples, mas já estou a algum tempo pesquisando e tentando e não encontrei nada que me ajuda-se.

**Problema**

Tenho uma lista do tipo `List<T>` que recebo como parâmetro de um outro método, e tenho que fazer uma chamada para um método que recebe `T...` como parâmetro.

**Pergunta**

Como eu faria para converter dinamicamente um `List<T>` para `T...`?

**Exemplo**

Para exemplificar, vou mostrar o que estou fazendo em minha situação real:

```java
private Object invokeMethodPrivateClassBase(Class<?> clazz,
        String nameMethod, List<Class<?>> paramsTypeClazz, Object... args) {
    try {
        // esse método 'getDeclaredMethod' recebe o primeiro parâmetro String e o segundo Object..., 
        // mas eu não posso receber 2 (dois) parametros '?...', pois só o ultimo pode ser desse tipo (por questões obvias).
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(nameMethod, paramsTypeClazz);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return method.invoke(AbsHorizontalListView.this, args);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Convertendo para `array` não funciona? Usando o `toArray`?

Comment: @Wakim, sim, tinha acabado de ver isso [aqui](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/), e ver que `T...`, nada mais é que `T[]`, então é só eu pegar minha `List<T> list` e dar um `list.toArray()` como você disse, valeu ai. Se você puder/quiser elaborar uma boa resposta para futuras pesquisas, eu analiso depois. (Tem horas que coisa simples parecem complicadas, hehe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preparei um exemplo funcional de como o método com argumentos variados deve ser chamado.

A ideia principal é você deve passar um array de parâmetros para o `invoke`, só que os argumentos de tamanho variado devem ser um outro array que será o último elemento do array principal.

Considere os comentários no código que explicam passo-a-passo o que ele faz:

```java
class Exemplo {

    private static Object invokeMethodPrivateClassBase(
            Class<?> clazz,
            Object instance,
            String nameMethod, 
            List<Class<?>> paramsTypeClazz, 
            Object... args) {
        try {

            //localiza o método
            Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(
                nameMethod, 
                paramsTypeClazz.toArray(new Class[paramsTypeClazz.size()]));

            //torna-o acessível mesmo sendo private
            method.setAccessible(true);

            //verifica se tem argumentos variados
            if (method.isVarArgs()) {

                //cria um array de parâmetros que deve ter a exata quantidade de parâmetros declarados,
                //isto é, sem considerar os argumentos variantes
                Object[] parameters = new Object[paramsTypeClazz.size()];

                //copia os parâmetros fixos para o novo array, desconsiderando apenas o último que é variante
                System.arraycopy(args, 0, parameters, 0, paramsTypeClazz.size() - 1);

                //calcula quantos argumentos variantes foram passados
                int varArgsSize = args.length - paramsTypeClazz.size() + 1;

                //cria um array com o tipo dos parâmetros variantes
                Object varArgsParameter = Array.newInstance(
                    paramsTypeClazz.get(paramsTypeClazz.size() - 1).getComponentType(), 
                    varArgsSize);

                //copia todos os demais argumentos para o array de argumentos variantes
                System.arraycopy(args, paramsTypeClazz.size() - 1, varArgsParameter, 0, varArgsSize);

                //coloca o array de argumentos variantes como último parâmetro para o método a ser chamado
                //isso porque o "..." equivale a um array
                parameters[paramsTypeClazz.size() - 1] = varArgsParameter;

                //chama o método
                return method.invoke(instance, parameters);
            } else {
                return method.invoke(instance, args);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            //apenas para teste
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "Y";
    }

    /**
     * Método de exemplo a ser chamado via reflexão 
     */
    public String meuMetodo(String label, Integer... valores) {
        Integer soma = 0;
        for (Integer v : valores) soma += v;
        return label + ": " + soma;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        //modo normal
        System.out.println(new Exemplo().meuMetodo("S1", 3, 4, 1));

        //prepara lista de tipos dos argumentos
        List<Class<?>> paramsTypeClazz = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        paramsTypeClazz.add(String.class);
        paramsTypeClazz.add(Integer[].class);

        //modo reflexivo
        System.out.println(Exemplo.invokeMethodPrivateClassBase(
            Exemplo.class,
            new Exemplo(),
            "meuMetodo",
            paramsTypeClazz,
            "S1", 3, 4, 1));
    }
}
```

### [Demo no Ideone](http://ideone.com/jpRkFb)

Comment: É até mais do que era esperado para a pergunta, pois nem necessitava chamar um método por _reflection_ que contivesse `varargs` ou "argumentos variados". Ótima explicação e implementação, cobrindo todas os cenários. +1 (Uma boa resposta assim eu esperava [nessa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27012/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-chamar-m%C3%A9todo-internalsem-operador-de-visibilidade-de-uma-class-her), hehe)

Comment: @Fernando A resposta do Kyllopardiun é basicamente o que eu recomendaria. Lá, colocar a classe no mesmo pacote não funciona porque o Java implementa restrições de segurança que impede o desenvolvedor de criar classes que executem no mesmo pacote de classes internas dele, evitando que elas acessem atributos e métodos que não deveriam. E a solução por *reflection* não é segredo, basta usar o `setAccessible` mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Esse método da classe [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) da API do Java recebe uma string e um varargs de `Class<?>`.
O real problema então é converter seu `List<Class<?>> paramsTypeClazz` para varargs ou um array.
Neste caso tente o seguinte (não testado):

```
Class<?>[] arrayDeClass = paramsTypeClass.toArray(new Class<?>[paramsTypeClass.size()]);
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(nameMethod, arrayDeClass);
```

Qualquer dúvida é só retornar.
Abraços

Comment: Sim funcionou corretamente, não tinha visto que `varargs` são a mesma coisa de Array ou `T... = T[]`, até que @Wakim citou nos comentários da pergunta. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. +1